# Oil spilled in my passport

Tags: indian-citizens, legal, applications, passport-renewals, damaged-passports

Is there any problem about this. I can't take new passport, there is no time left. So please give me advice.
My passport got spilled by oil on the first page. But there is no problem about the picture and name, but still there remains oil mark, is there any problem?

In Moscow airport.
I called Indian embassy they said you have to get a new passport but it takes two months I had booked my ticket to India on June so there is no enough time ne to get new passport. Will I face any problem? There is no mark on the back side barcode[image: photo of the damaged passport]

Comment: also tweet to @passportsevamea. They may provide some help

Comment: They need police certificate to issue you duplicate passport within 1 week. I think in your case is damaged passport so you have to apply for reissue of passport in Moscow. If it is urgent, they can issue you emergency certificate for travel to india within 1 day.  see: http://www.indianembassy.ru/index.php/en/consular-services/information-related-to-consular-services-and-document-checklist

Comment: Is there any problem relating to scanning the passport ....

Comment: Akshaya Krishnan- were you able to travel with the passport? Actually I have the same issue. Could you please provide some updates!

Answer (score 4):

[India's passport website](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports) says the following

> Q1:   What is the definition of damaged passport?
>
> A:    Damaged passport is classified further based on the extent of
>   damage, i.e.:
>
> 1. Damaged Passport - Passport number is readable, name is legible and
>      photo is intact
> 2. Damaged beyond recognition

Im sure your home country will let you in(Maybe with some questioning). It would have been more of an issue if you were travelling to another country. My advice would be to have your passport open on the picture page when you hand it to the border officer. Usually they don't even look at other pages when you are coming home.

Comment: I just read it ... in my passport there is only oil mark noother problem

Comment: Am studying on Russia and also booked my ticket on June so there is no time for new passport

Comment: @AkshayaKrishnan Well you have no choice but to fly home with it. From Indian passport website it doesn't sound like a problem, plus you have the bonus that you are flying to your home country not trying to get into a foreign country.